# Using Apply to avoid "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"?

Tags: r

I'm trying to define a piece-wise function, and it works fine for single inputs, but when I try to use a vector input, I get the "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" error because it's passing a scalar into a vector as far as I can tell.

```
ex <- function(x){
  if (x < -1) {
    y <- (-2 * x) -2
    return(y)
  }
  else if (-1 <= x & x <= 1) {
    y <- 0
    return(y)
  }
  else if (1 < x){
    y <- (x * x) - 1
    return(y)
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me use an apply function to fix this issue? I'd like to avoid using ifelse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, your function is written only for scalar inputs and not for vectors. So,

```
ex(10)
ex(12)
```

works. But,

```
ex(c(10, 12))
```

doesn't. (Actually it gives the expected output with a warning in this case)

---

Without changing the function one way is to use `sapply`

```
sapply(c(10, 12), ex)
```

---

Or you can change the function and use `ifelse` which will work for vectors

```
ex1 <- function(x){
   ifelse(x < -1,(-2 * x) -2,
     ifelse(-1 <= x & x <= 1, 0,
       ifelse(1 < x,(x * x) - 1,NA)))
}

ex1(c(10, 12))
```

Or with `dplyr::case_when`

```
ex2 <- function(x){
   dplyr::case_when(x < -1 ~ (-2 * x) -2,
                   -1 <= x & x <= 1 ~ 0,
                    1 < x ~ (x * x) - 1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what I'm looking for is something where I can call the function directly. Eg ex(10) gives me an output, I want to integrate sapply into the function itself to allow the answer to loop through rather than applying sapply to the function call

Comment: @MrArtichokeMan `ex1` and `ex2` should work as per your expectations.

Comment: I'd like to work it out to get a better understanding of sapply, but this does indeed give me the proper output. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @MrArtichokeMan what you can do is keep your `ex` as it is and create another function with `sapply` `ex1 <- function(x) sapply(x, ex)` and then use `ex1(c(10, 12))`.

Comment: That is perfect and solved the issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Just to showcase `Vectorize` here, which is another way of vectorizing your functions, i.e.

```
ex_vec <- Vectorize(ex)

ex_vec(c(10, 12))
#[1]  99 143
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely keep that in mind, great idea and great input!